# Forcing Windows Authentication to use HTTPS on IIS

Tags: django, iis, windows-authentication

Running a Django app on IIS, URL Rewrite set up on IIS and SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True in settings.py.

My problem is that it appears that the log-in window is asking for credentials over HTTP before redirecting to HTTPS despite everything else on the site redirecting properly. Am I mistaken and the sign-in occurs over HTTPS despite the address bar initially coming up as HTTP, or is there another way to force the sign-in over HTTPS? Or is this just a limitation of Windows Authentication?

We're a Windows shop here, so logging in with our Windows credentials is huge, and I'd like to handle this with IIS if possible. I do remember stumbling across some Django/Python packages that can plug into AD and do the authorization that way (which should fix the HTTP issue if there's no workaround), so I'm not opposed to a little extra work - just want to make sure we're secure :)

Let me know if I need to provide any more info/clarification, and advice or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817643.aspx#authaspdotnet_authentication), using Basic Authentication is the move to make. We went with this plus an HTTP Redirect to force HTTPS as our Authentication solution.